# Points of finite order on $y^2=x^3+Dx$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am interested in the following problem:

> Prove that points of finite order on the curve $ y^2=x^3+Dx$ where $D$ is non zero integer is described as follows:
> $$\{P\in C (\mathbb Q): P \text{ has finite order}\}\cong\begin{cases}\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z &\text{if $D=4d^4$ for some $d$}\\ \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \bigoplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z &\text{if $D=-d^4$ for some $d$}\\ \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I came across the above problem in exercise 3 from the book *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by *Joseph H. Silverman*. We of course need to use Nagell–Lutz theorem, however, I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about the second case? I reckon if $D=-d^2$ then there are four points of order $2$.

Comment: The LMFDB curve [32.a3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/32/a/3) ($y^2=x^3-x$) has group structure $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which has $3$ points of order $2$ and the identity of order $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the OP is Exercise III.3.7 (c)** at page 1041-05 in [Silverman, Tate: Rational points on elliptic curves]. Since it comes with a double asterisk, we will deal equivalently with an other exercise.

This is Exercise IV.4.9 at page 142 in [Silverman, Tate: Rational points on elliptic curves], it deals with curves over $\Bbb Q$
$$
E(b)\ :\ y^2 = x^3 + bx\ ,
$$
where $b$ is a non-zero integer which is fourth power free.

---

Note: If $b$ is (initially) rational with a denominator $>1$, multiply with the fourth power of the denominator to get an integer instead. Then eliminate the primes at powers $\ge 4$ in the prime factor decomposition using the observation, that the curve
$
y^2=x^3+bu^4x
$ can be written equivalently after division with $u^6$ as $(y/u^3)=(x/u^2)^3+b(x/u^2)$ and the substitution $X=x/u^2$, $Y=y/u^3$ leads to an equation of type of $E(b)$ in $(X,Y)$.

Note: In *loc. cit.* the letter used for the coefficient in $x$ is $b$, not $D$ as in the OP and in Exercise III.3.7 (c)**. (So we have $D$ still available for the discriminant $D=-4b^3$.)

---

> Then the exercise claims that the group $\Phi =E(\Bbb Q)_{\text{torsion}}$, the subgroup of rational points of $E$ over $\Bbb Q$ of finite order...
>
> - (a) has order dividing $4$, and
> - (b) the following structure description appear depending on $b$:
> - (b1) $\Phi\cong \Bbb Z/4$ if $b=4$,
> - (b2) $\Phi\cong \Bbb Z/2\oplus\Bbb Z/2$ if $-b$ is a square,
> - (b3) $\Phi\cong \Bbb Z/2$ in the remaining cases.

---

For the convenience of the reader, let us recall the Exercise 4.8 preceding the Exercise 4.9:

> Let $p$ be a prime which is $3$ modulo $4$, we work with curves over $F=\Bbb F_p$, and let us also consider $b\in\Bbb F_p^\times$. Then:
>
> - (a) The following quartic (affine) equation $(Q)$  has $(p-1)$ solutions $(u,v)$ over $F$: $$ (Q)\ :\ v^2 = u^4-4b\ . $$
> - (b) From a solution $(u,v)$ of the equation $(Q)$ in (a) we can construct a solution $(x,y)$ of the equation $(E)$ $y^2=x^3 +bx$ by setting $$
>   \begin{aligned}
>   x &=(u^2+v)/2\ ,\\
>   y &= ux=u(u^2+v)/2\ .
>   \end{aligned}
>   $$
> - (c) The (projective) curve $(E)$ has $|E(F)|=(p+1)$ points over $F=\Bbb F_p$, also counting the infinity point.

---

The Exercise  4.8 comes with small steps. In (a) we note that the cyclic group $F^\times$ has $(p-1)$ elements, which is $2$ modulo four. Then both maps $u\to u^4$ and $v\to v^2$ have as image the subgroup $G=(F^\times)^2$ of odd order $(p-1)/2$ and index two in $F^\times$. Note that squaring is an isomorphism of $G$. We then work with the new variable $U=u^2$, and it remains to count for every element (in our case $-4b$) in $F$ the representations as difference $v^2-U^2$ of two squares. It is enough to consider the elements $\pm 1$. We may exchange $u\leftrightarrow v$, wo we have to count the number of solutions for $v^2-U^2=1$.
With the same argument, all equations of the shape $v^2-U^2=-4b$ have the same number of solutions, $b\ne 0$. We count separately the case $b=0$, there are $1+2(p-1)=2p-1$ realizations, $v=0$ is one of them, for the other values of $v$ we have to take $U=\pm v$. So each of the equations $v^2-U^2=-4b$ has
$$\frac{p^2-(2p-1)}{p-1}=(p-1)
$$
solutions. This gives (a). For (b) we simply check:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y^2 - x^3  
&=
\frac 18(u^2+v)^2\Big[\ 2u^2-(u^2+v)\ \Big]
=
\frac 18(u^2+v)^2(u^2-v)
=
\frac 18(u^2+v)(u^4-v^2)
\\
&=
\frac 18(u^2+v)4b=bx\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For (c), we observe that for each point $(x,y)$ with $x\ne 0$ we can uniquely associate $u=y/x$, which determines $v$. It remains to consider $x=0$ and the infinity point.

---

Now we come back to 4.9 and are in position to apply the theorem (Reduction mod $p$ Theorem, page 123) saying roughly that for all but finitely many primes $p$ the composition $\Phi\to E(\Bbb Q)\to E(\Bbb F_p)$ is an injection, thus the order of $\Phi$ divides $E(\Bbb F_p)$. Using IV.4.8, $|\Phi|$ divides $(p+1)$ for all but finitely many values of $p$ which are $3$ modulo four. For prime **density** reasons $|\Phi|$ divides $4$.

(This density argument is the canon tool used to move the double asterisk to an other front.)

---

The Exercise IV.4.9 reduces now to the study of all possibilities for the group $\Phi$ of order either $2$ or $4$. Since the point $(0,0)$ is a two-torsion point.

- The situation of a group $\Phi$ of the shape $\Bbb Z/2\oplus \Bbb Z/2$ is possible if there is an other point of order two. Such a point has the $y$-component zero, so the equation $x^3+bx=0$ must have further solutions, so $b$ is minus a square. This is the case (b2).
- The situation $\Phi=\Bbb Z/4$ is possible, iff there is a point $T(s,t)$ with $2T=(0,0)$. [Point doubling formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling) show that after considering the slope $m=(3s^2+b)/(2t)$ of the curve in $T$ we have $0=m^2-2s$ and $0=m(s-0)-t$. Together with the equation of the curve $t^2=s(s^2+b)$ we eliminate $m$, get
  $$
  t^2=\frac s2(3s^2+b) = 2s^3=s(s^2+b)\ .
  $$
  So $b=s^2$ is a square, and from $t^2=2s^3$ we have $s=2d^2$. This leads to $b=s^2=4d^4$, which is case (b1).
- In any other situation $|\Phi|\ne 4$, so $|\Phi|$ remains $2$, and $\Phi$ is generated by $(0,0)$, the situation (b3).

Answer (score 1):

Dan Fulea has given a great answer. I'll give a different approach to showing that for $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ of good reduction $\# \tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p) = p + 1$.

We can throw out finitely many $p$, so discard $3$ (so that $\tilde{E}$ is given by $y^2 = f(x) = x^3 + \tilde{D}x$) and notice that $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Also, in general we have
$$\# \tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p) = 1 + \sum_{a \in \mathbb{F}_p}\left( \left(\frac{f(a)}{p} \right) + 1\right)$$
where $\left(\frac{\text{ }}{\text{ }} \right)$ is the Legendre symbol. For $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ we have that $-1$ is not a square, so
\begin{align*}
\# \tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p) &= 1 + \left( \left(\frac{f(0)}{p} \right) + 1 \right) + \sum_{0 < a \leq \frac{p-1}{2}}\left( \left(\frac{f(a)}{p} \right) + \left(\frac{f(-a)}{p} \right) + 2\right) \\
&= 2 + 2 \left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right) \\
&= p + 1
\end{align*}